# Java 8 multiple mapping

Tags: java, java-8, functional-interface

Is it possible perform multiple mapping on collection?
Following code compilation error:

> ... in Stream cannot be applied to `java.util.function.Function<capture<?>,capture<?>>`

```
private static List<?> multipleMapping(final Collection<?> collection, final List<Function<?, ?>> functions) {
    Stream<?> stream = collection.stream();
    for (Function<?, ?> function : functions) {
        stream = stream.map(function);
    }
    return stream.collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

I would like to generic solution.

Comment: Do the `Function`s all return the same type as their input, or can they return different types?

Comment: How many functions do you have, maximum?

Comment: And what is the type returned by the last function?

Comment: Probably in any case it will be Comparable <String or BigDecimal or Integer or something else Comparable>

Comment: @Artur And what about the maximum number of functions? Are we talking about a couple, 3, 4 or 5, or dozens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have few functions (i.e. if you can write them down), then I suggest you don't add them to a list. Instead, compose them into a single function, and then apply that single function to each element of the given collection.

Your `multipleMapping()` method would now receive a single function:

```
public static <T, R> List<R> multipleMapping(
    Collection<T> collection, Function<T, R> function) {

    return collection.stream()
            .map(function)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Then, in the calling code, you could create a function composed of many functions (you will have all the functions anyway) and invoke the `multipleMapping()` method with that function.

For example, suppose we have a list of candidates:

```
List<String> candidates = Arrays.asList(
        "Hillary", "Donald",
        "Bernie", "Ted", "John");
```

And four functions:

```
Function<String, Integer> f1 = String::length;

Function<Integer, Long> f2 = i -> i * 10_000L;

Function<Long, LocalDate> f3 = LocalDate::ofEpochDay;

Function<LocalDate, Integer> f4 = LocalDate::getYear;
```

These functions can be used to compose a new function, as follows:

```
Function<String, Integer> function = f1.andThen(f2).andThen(f3).andThen(f4);
```

Or also this way:

```
Function<String, Integer> composed = f4.compose(f3).compose(f2).compose(f1);
```

Now, you can invoke your `multipleMapping()` method with the list of candidates and the composed `function`:

```
List<Integer> scores = multipleMapping(candidates, function);
```

So we have transformed our list of candidates into a list of scores, by explicitly composing a new function from four different functions and applying this composed function to each candidate.

If you want to know who will win the election, you could check which candidate has the highest score, but I will let that as an exercise for whoever is interested in politics ;)

Comment: Composing function looks better and it kept type control. Thanks @Federico. Your solution solves my problem.

Answer (score 9):

The problem comes from the fact that you're using a generic wildcard `?`. What you want is to have a parameterized type `T`, that will represent the type of the Stream element. Assuming the function would return the same type as their input, you could have:

```
private static <T> List<T> multipleMapping(final Collection<T> collection, final List<Function<T, T>> functions) {
    Stream<T> stream = collection.stream();
    for (Function<T, T> function : functions) {
        stream = stream.map(function);
    }
    return stream.collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

This compiles fine: the mapper given to `map` correcly accepts a `T` and returns a `T`. However, if the functions don't return the same type as their input then you won't be able to keep type-safety and will have to resort to using `List<Function<Object, Object>>`.

---

Note that we could use a [`UnaryOperator<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/UnaryOperator.html) instead of `Function<T, T>`.

Also, you could avoid the `for` loop and reduce all functions into a single one using `andThen`:

```
private static <T> List<T> multipleMapping(final Collection<T> collection, final List<Function<T, T>> functions) {
    return collection.stream()
                     .map(functions.stream().reduce(Function.identity(), Function::andThen))
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's fine. But i have different Functions, e.g: A -> B -> C -> D - not T -> T

Comment: @akfmb Then you can't have type-safety. The best you can have is a `List<Function<Object, Object>>` is you want to be as general as possible. If you want type-safety, you could do is have multiple overloaded method `multipleMapping(List<T>, Function<T, R1>, Function<R1, R>`, etc...

Comment: You should compose the functions outside the stream, so you don't compose them for each element of the collection

Comment: My list of the functions have sometimes 1 element - sometimes 2,3,4 - the number of elements is not constant.
So I think that (as @Tunaki said) the best option for me is to use Object.